# HTMLElements: element search timeout

Tags: testing, htmlelements

It seems that [HTMLElements](https://github.com/yandex-qatools/htmlelements) by default waits for element during 5 seconds. Is there any way to change this default timeout duration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In current release it's not possible. But we have an open pull-request (https://github.com/yandex-qatools/htmlelements/pull/63) implementing this feature. We can't accept it right now because there are issues need to be fixed first and PR's author have no time to do this. You can help fixing this issues and we'll release a new version right away.